# Publish Web Site + reverse engineer and get back .aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Actually those 2 links talks about the .net Reflector.  But my problem is that when we choose the PUBLISH WEBSITE option for a WebSite in Visual Studio, and then in the next window that comes up, uncheck all the 3 options which are

1. Allow this precompiled site to be updatable  --> Not Checked
2. Use fixed naming and singe page assemblies  -->Not Checked.
3. Enable strong naming on pre-compiled assemblies  --> Not Checked.

In the location where the files are placed , we can see .aspx file which has the content This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!.

Now in the current scenario that I can  facing, some person has published the website , using the PUBLISH WEB SITE option and then deleted the existing dotnet code.  Now if I reverse engineer using the .Net Reflector, I get back .aspx.cs files, but I cannot get back the .aspx files.. Actually  the .aspx file contents are represented as a class which inherits from the Page Class of dotnet.  Below is the sample snippet what I get from the reflector

```
public class HomePage : Page, IRequiresSessionState
{
    // Fields
    protected HtmlForm Form1;
    protected Literal InvalidPortalHeader;
    protected Literal InvalidPortalText;
    protected Table Table1;
```

.................. Something like this.

If code is generated in this format, then I will have to add new controls to the webpage in this format. Is there a way that I can get back the .aspx file also (not only the .aspx.cs file), so that I can add new controls like Label, Textbox at design time using my Visual Studio.

Is there any idea to get that .aspx file with original code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Find a Delorean and go back in time, and put your code in source control...

Comment: If you keep looking in your decompiled code, you'll find code which builds the markup, but it's pretty craptastic. I just did a simple website, and it generated a class with namespace `ASP` and class named `default_aspx`, and in this class was enough information to build the webform, and includes all the HTML from the page plus the controls. It won't get you the original ASPX file, but it might help you rebuild it by hand.